# javascript change onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick

I have a script that enables my uses to block / unblock users. They're both in the same function 'blockToggle(type, user, button)' and depending on the type( either block or unblock) it executes that script. But what I'm trying to do is if the current user doesnt have another user blocked, they can block them with the button, but when the user clicks the button, they have to refresh the page to unblock the user. I want the onclick attribute to change right away once the user clicks it without refreshing the page. Here are a few things i've tried:.

```
document.getElementById("blockBtn").onclick = "blockToggle('unblock', 'user', 'blockBtn')";

document.getElementById("blockBtn").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: blockToggle('unblock', 'user', 'blockBtn')";

document.getElementById("blockBtn").onclick = function(){ "blockToggle('unblock', 'user', 'blockBtn')"};
```

Neither one of these solutions worked for me. And I couldn't seem to find a solution from google search either. Is there anything I'm overseeing here? I'm sure the answers right in front of me.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Look how the code is highlighted.

Comment: Are `unblock`, `user`, and `blockBtn` supposed to be literal strings or variable names? If they're variables, you shouldn't put them in quotes.

Comment: the only one thats a variable is user, which in my actual code i don't have them it quotes

Comment: I actually think it was a syntax error in my code :O i just deleted it all and wrote it again and using the .setAttribute function in javascript worked.

Comment: If you just had a typo error please delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how your function `blockToggle()` looks like, but try this, without the extra quotes:

```
document.getElementById("blockBtn").onclick = function(){ 
    blockToggle(unblock, user, blockBtn);
};
```

I am assuming your function `blockToggle` is declared and that `unblock` `user` & `blockBtn` are declared variables also.

Comment: I think unblock, user and blockBtn are strings

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from setting handlers as strings. Just use a normal anonymous function that calls your `blockToggle`.

```
document.getElementById("blockBtn").onclick = function(){ 
    blockToggle('unblock', 'user', 'blockBtn');
};
```